# How to let user select which arg to print

Tags: python, arguments

As a way to learn python, I am building  Yahtzee.py.

After the first roll, I would like the user to decide what to keep or what to reroll (up to 3 times).

So as to avoid writing a code for every scenario how can I allow user to select which dice to reroll. ie( keep die 1 or  keep dice 2, 3,5)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    import random

rollCount=1
roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
roll3 = random.randint(1,6)
roll4 = random.randint(1,6)
roll5 = random.randint(1,6)

def rollAll():
    roll1
    roll2
    roll3
    roll4
    roll5



def printAll():
    print("roll 1:",roll1,"\nroll 2:",roll2,"\nroll 3:",roll3,"\nroll 4:",roll4,"\nroll 5:",roll5)

def printRoll():

print("press any key to roll dice")
input()
str(printAll())
print("Would you like to roll again?\nroll all, roll 1, roll 2 , roll 3, roll 4 , roll 5")
rollAgain = input()
if rollAgain== "roll all":
    rollCount=2
    rollAll()
    str(printAll())
```

Comment: The Code Repetition is strong in this one.

Comment: please fix your indentation

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Python! :)

As your post indicates that this is a learning exercise, I will offer advice for objectives you should try to reach, rather than writing and pasting your code for you.

Your program needs to remember the roll for each die. One of many mechanisms for this could be:

```
outcomes = []
for i in range(0,5):
    outcomes.append(random.randint(1,6))
```

Given the above, you now have programmatic memory of each outcome. Each of the random.randint() outcomes are now kept in a list, which you can access by element later in your program, depending on what the user chooses to keep or reroll. Remember that the user's perception of "die one" is actually element zero in your list, due to the way indices are numbered.

There are over a dozen ways to approach the remainder of your program, but this should be a good starter, for you. You could even explore list comprehensions to improve on the sample I provide, above.

Comment: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. Use `outcomes.append(...)`.

Comment: doh! And here I was thinking I could get away without .append() or testing in the interpreter. Thank you; will fix.

Comment: And it escaped me that this range has only 5 elements. Can't edit it in, too short.